# How do i get my program to calculate the average dropping the lowest score?

Tags: c++, average

Below is my code: It runs well but how can make it average all scores entered by the user but drop the lowest score before calculating? I've inserted some code but I believe its wrong because I can't get it to work right. Is there a shorter, simplest way to write that code? Or the best way to write it? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//void sortArray(double arr[], int numTest, int scoreNum);
//void displayArray(double arr[], int numTest, int scoreNum);

int main()
{
    //To dynamically allocate an array, Accumulator, to hold the average scores.
    double *score;      
    double total = 0;  
    double average; 


    //int for counter, to hold the number of test scores.
    int count; 
    int numTest; 


    // To obtain the number of test scores the user would like to enter.
    cout << "How many test scores would you like to enter? " << endl;
    cin >> numTest; 


    //Dynamically allocates an array large enough to hold the amount of test scores to enter.
    score = new double[numTest];


    //Get the test scores.
    cout << "Enter the test score desired. " << endl;
    for (count = 0; count < numTest; count++)
    {
        cout << "Score " << (count + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> score[count];
    }

    //sortArray(score, numTest, scoreNum); (Need to get this part to work)
    //displayArray( score, numTest, scoreNum); (Need to get this part to work)

    //Calculate the total test scores.
    for (count = 0; count < numTest; count++)
    {
        total += score[count];
    }

    //Calculate the test scores average minus the lowest score. (I need help here - is this how I drop the lowest score?)
    average = total / numTest;

    //Display the results
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Test Scores Average with the lowest dropped is: " << average << endl;

    //Free dynamically allocated memory
    delete [] score;
    score = 0; // Makes score point to null.

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

/* void sortArray(double arr[], int numTest, int scoreNum)
{
    double num = 0;
    int posNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numTest; i++)
    {
        for (int x = (i + 1); x < numTest; x++)
        {
            if ( arr[i] > arr[x] )
            {
                num = score[i];
                posNum = scoreNum[i];
                arr[i] = arr[x];
                scoreNum[i] = scoreNum[x];
                arr[x] = num;
                scoreNum[x] = posNum;
            }
        }
    }
}

void displayArray(double arr[], int numTest, int scoreNum)
{
    double average = 0.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i < numTest; i++)
    {
        for (x = 1; x < numTest; x++)
        {
            sum += arr[x];
        }
    }

    average = sum(numTest - 1);

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;
    cout << "The average of all test scores dropping the lowest is: " << average << endl;
}
*/
```

Comment: What problems are you having with your code?

Comment: Sorting seems like overkill for finding the lowest value.  Change score to be a vector<double> then do this:

    double minScore = 1e6; int minScoreIndex;
    for(count=0;count<numTest;count++) { if(minScore>score[count]) { minScore=score[count]; minScoreIndex=count; } }
    score.erase(score.begin()+minScoreIndex);

Comment: I need to get it to drop the lowest score and then calculate it. Right now I can only get it to calculate the total scores without dropping the lowest score. I am a little unclear as to how to appropriately write the function to drop the lowest score. I wrote something down (which I commented out at the bottom) but I am not getting that to work at all. Could I use something like, voidFindLowest... and then average = total / (numTest - lowest) ? Or do i have to have a sort array and then find the lowest and then drop it and display it?

Comment: Thank you DigitalGhost. I think she wants the score to remain a pointer. Does the same work with pointer? The lecture on it has been very minimal.

Comment: If you want to minimize your code hit, while still getting the *answer* you're looking for, GraphicsMuncher's answer below is entirely correct for dropping the lowest score and computing the (score count-1) average.

Comment: :-) Thank you. I'm on it. I really appreciate everyone's response. I am new at this so all of your input has helped me enormously. I have gone with GraphicsMuncher's response.. no offense to anyone. His is the shortest one and the one i think my teacher is looking for.

Comment: @user1787078 Don't forget to accept the answer that you think is best :)

Comment: I just did but I might have to use yours if this other one doesn't work. Its the 2nd closest to what I think she might want. tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have all of the scores, iterate through them to find the lowest one. A simple iteration will work fine:

```
int lowest = score[0];
for(count = 1; count < numTest; count++)
{
    if(score[count] < lowest) lowest = score[count];
}
```

Now `lowest` will hold the lowest score. You can subtract it from your total and divide by `numTest-1` and you should be all set.

Comment: It's a degenerate case. I suppose it isn't really bubble sort at that point then...

Comment: I am still having a hard time using this code. let me see if it'll let me submit some of it.

Comment: //Find lowest score.
 int lowest = score[count];
 for (count = 1; count < numTest; count++)
 {
  if (score[count] < lowest) 
   lowest = score[count];
 }


 //Calculate the total test scores.
 for (count = 0; count < numTest; count++)
 {
  total += score[count];
  total -= lowest;
 }

 //Calculate the test scores average minus the lowest score. 
 average = total / (numTest - 1);

 //Display the results
 cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
 cout << "Test Scores Average with the lowest dropped is: " << average << endl;

Comment: @user1787078 the only bug I see in your code is the initial value for lowest is set wrong. you have `lowest = score[count];`. That should be `lowest = score[0];` the rest looks good.

Comment: I changed that to score[0]; and got the following: Enter the test score desired: Score 1: 89, Score 2: 85, Score 3: 59, Score 4: 78, Score 5: 98. Test Scores average with the lowest dropped is: 102.25. As you can see, its not dropping the lowest and calculating properly. :-(

Comment: Like I said, subtract the lowest score from the total. You did not do that. `average = (total - lowest)/(numTest - 1);`

Answer (score 3):

Before we begin, you should consider using `std::vector` instead of a raw pointer for your array.

```
// instead of:
double *score = new double[numTest];

// use:
std::vector<double> scores;
scores.resize(numTest);
```

On to your question:

First, you need to sort the scores to find the lowest:

```
// partial_sort will find the first n (here, 1) items, and leave the remainder
std::partial_sort(&score[0], &score[1], &score[numTest]);
```

Next, get the average of all but the lowest:

```
auto avg = std::accumulate(&score[1], &score[numTest], 0.0) / (numTest - 1);
```

(This is skipping over all error-handling; for instance, you should be checking that `numTest` is greater than 1.)

Comment: Sorting the scores is overkill for excluding the lowest score from the average.

Comment: @ktodisco: you're right. I'm in the middle of editing it now.

Comment: @moswald: May I also suggest `scores.begin() + 1` instead of `&scores[1]`. Looks nicer, and feels more type-sound.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Actually, I prefer the `&scores[1]` version. Scott Meyers does, too (at least, he did when he wrote the version of *Effective STL* that I have).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, she wants us to use the raw pointer. But this is good to know for future. This seems to be one of her favorite things to ask for.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Another reason for `&scores[1]` over `scores.begin() + 1`: changing the type from `std::vector<double>` to `double *` didn't affect the rest of the code.

Comment: @moswald: True. It’s not a huge issue, of course, just a thought. I should have said `std::begin(scores) + 1` and `std::end(scores)` anyway, since that works for containers and arrays alike, with no mixing of types.

Answer (score 0):

To do it efficiently (avoiding as many instructions as possible), you can track the lowest score at the same time you sum your values, thus only having to loop over your scores once.

```
double lowest = MAX_SCORE;
//Calculate the total test scores.
for (count = 0; count < numTest; count++)
{
    if (score[count] < lowest)
        lowest = score[count];
    total += score[count];
}
total -= lowest;
average = total / (numTest - 1);
```

Comment: Awesome. This is what i had in mind but couldn't put it together. Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it has the potential to introduce far more rounding errors than a summation of a sorted array.

Comment: @ktodisco: The effect is rather minor, but adding a small value to a large value is likely to lose more information (through truncation) than adding a small value to a small value. See the difference in the results in this example code: http://liveworkspace.org/code/a6bf9a210c1cb21de21d927d3635410b

Comment: @Mankarse Interesting, though that concern is probably beyond the scope of what the asker is looking for.  Thanks though, an intriguing bit of information to know!

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<double> scores;
// populate scores here
double lowest = scores[0];
double sum = scores[0];
for (int i = 1; i < scores.size(); ++i) {
    lowest = std::min(lowest, scores[i]);
    sum += scores[i];
}
sum -= lowest;
sum /= scores.size() - 1;
```